# Find All the controls in a form using jQuery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a starter in jQuery . How to find all the controls in a form using jQuery?

I know the code is like this

```
function submitValidator(){
   $("form :input").each(function(){ });
```

I want to access their Id's and need to apply regular expressions

Some of the text boxes are numeric remaining will be alphanumeric. Is there any method to sort them to apply regular expressions?

Comment: what do you want to do with the regular expressions? do you want to select only certain ids or...?

Comment: what do you want to do with the regex

Comment: @ArunPJohny you know for text box and text area  i have to check whether it is numeric or alphanumeric.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a new property data-charSet in HTML

`<input type="text" id='amt' data-charSet='numeric'>`

add which all controlles you want to add after the "form :"

```
function submitValidator(){
                   $("form :text, textarea").each(function(){         
                        var NumericOnly = "^[0-9]*$";
                        var svId = $(this).attr('id');
            if($(this).attr('data-charSet') == 'numericonly')
                    {
                         if(!$(this).val().match(NumericOnly)) { 
                            alert("numeric");
                            eval("$('#" + svId +"').focus();")
                            return false;
                            }
                    }
                    });
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's *jQuery*, not *j-query*.
Anyway...

You can do it like this:

```
$("form :input").each(function (index, element) { 
    var id = $(this).attr("id"); // returns the object ID
    var value = $(this).val(); // returns the object value
    // etc
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
function submitValidator() { 
   $("form :input").each(function(){ 
       var id = $(this).attr('id'); // here you got id
   });
} // here missed brace
```

Answer (score 0):

you need not to get Id if you can get object

```
function submitValidator() { 
   $("form :input ,form textarea").each(function(){ 
    $(this).yourfunction();
   });
}
```

:input will only give you tags with input, textarea will be missed so need to add that as well

Comment: Actually textarea, button, and select are all matched by `:input`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
$("form").find("input").each(function(){ 
   var currentElementsId = $(this).attr("id");
   if(currentElementsId.match(/^regex/)){
      //do something
   }
});
```

if you want to get more than only input elements inside the form tag, you can put multiple selectors in the `find()` function like this; `find("input,select,textarea,.className,[type='valueOfAttributeType']")` and obviously any other selectors